# Restrict the access to a component for specific user profile

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

i'am developing a lightning aura component and i need to restrict the access for specific user profile. How can i process?

Comment: Where are you putting the component? Record page, home page?

Comment: thanks, i put it in a homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag your component onto the Lightning page. Click on the component and then select "add filters" on the right

[image]

Select "Advanced" and then click "select"

[image]

Search for User and select --> Search for "Profile" and select --> Search for "Name" and select and then click "Done".

[image]

Finish your filter with your specific profile name

[image]

Click "Done" and then click "Save"

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.